# How to compile with a lower API level? android:targetSdkVersion is ignored by Ant

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to check whether my app uses any object/method that does not exist on Android 1.5 (=API level 3), so I wrote in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk  android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="3"/>
```

... then I ran `ant clean debug` and:

**PROBLEM:** Ant still uses the highest SDK level I have installed (11), not the one I want (3):

```
-setup:
[echo] Gathering info for AnkiDroid...
[setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 15
[setup] Project Target: Android 3.0
[setup] API level: 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to set the target SDK for your project.
There are multiple ways to do that

- In Eclipse
  Right click on the project in eclipse, go to properties -> android and select a target SDK from the list.
- Via the command line
  Use `android update project -t <targetID>` as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/android.html), where `<targetID>` is one of the target ids that you get listed by executing `android list targets`.

You can see the current target in the `project.properties` file in your project folder, it should have a line like this:

> target=android-14

*(it might also work to edit this file directly. I'm not sure though, so if you try that, be prepared and have a backup, expect things to break, etc. ;) )*